# JDBC resultset related

Tags: java, database, jdbc, resultset

I have this piece of code in JDBC (worked upon in NetBeans IDE 8.1) which is not pulling data from the 2nd result set. Have tried going through several answers but no solution till now........

The code I have written is pasted below:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    Connection conn= null;
    Statement stmt1= null;
    Statement stmt2= null;
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>Servlet test_servlet</title>");
        out.println("<link href=\"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">");
        out.println("<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js\"></script>");
        out.println("<script src=\"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>");
        out.println("</head><body>");
        out.println("<div class=\"container-fluid\">");

        //Register Driver
        out.println("<h5>Trying to register</h5>");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        out.println("<h5>Registered successfully</h5>");

        //Open a connection
        out.println("<h5>Trying to connect to the XE database...</h5>");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Toshiba:1521:xe","SYSTEM","oraclee");
        out.println("<h5>Connected Successfully</h5>");

        //Executing queries
        stmt1=conn.createStatement();
        stmt2=conn.createStatement();

        String [] subj=new String[5];
        int i=0;
        ResultSet rst1=stmt1.executeQuery("select * from TESTINGTABLE");
        while(rst1.next()){
            //int numb=rst.getInt(1);
            subj[i]=rst1.getString("E_NAME").toString();
            out.println("Hello "+subj[i]);
            out.println("<br>");
            i++;
        }
        rst1.close();

        ResultSet rst2=stmt2.executeQuery("select * from TESTTABLE");
        while(rst2.next()){
            String antt=rst2.getString(1).toString();
            out.println("Hi "+antt+"<br>");
        }
        rst2.close();
        out.println("<h5>Result set object closed</h5>");
        stmt2.close();
        stmt1.close();
        out.println("<h5>Statement object closed</h5>");
        conn.close();
        out.println("<h5>Connection object closed</h5>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output it provides me is:

```
Trying to register
Registered successfully
Trying to connect to the XE database...
Connected Successfully
Hello Joe
Hello Chris
Hello James
Hello Eve
Hello Thomas
```

It isn't displaying data from 2nd resultset.

The two tables I am using in this program are given below:

1> TESTINGTABLE having only one column (E_NAME) with 5 values in it
Joe, Chris, James, Eve, Thomas

2> TESTTABLE having only one column (E_NAME) with 1 value in it
Mariam

Comment: Does it return Mariam If you select from the TESTTABLE first? I mean if the stmt1 selects from the TESTTABLE.

Comment: Please edit your question to have a more descriptive title, and any exceptions that have been printed out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `'` at the end of `"select * from TESTTABLE'"` will cause an error. You should have a stacktrace with an exception

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
ResultSet rst2=stmt2.executeQuery("select * from TESTTABLE'");
                                                          ^ -- here
```

try to remove the last `'` on the SQL query, as this

```
ResultSet rst2=stmt2.executeQuery("select * from TESTTABLE");
```

Comment: Even then it is not displaying 'Mariam'